# Some of HTML tags are not working properly in Angular 12

Tags: html, angular, tags

I don't have any error regarding this issue. But this is the proof that my tag is not working.
[image]
This is literally my HTML file. There is no error in my cmd and all its just h1, h2 and so on tags doesn't work. The reason is still unknown to me.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Customer List</h1>  <!--This is not working properly-->
    <table class="table ">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Contact Number</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Valid ID</th>
            <th>Credit Limit</th>
            <th>Consignment</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let x of customer">
                <td>{{x.Fname}} {{x.Mname}} {{x.Lname}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Contact_no}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Address}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Valid_id}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Credit_Limit}}</td>
                <td>{{x.total}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-outline-danger w-100" (click)="pick(x.CustomerID)">PICK</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
</div>
```

The Customer List on top is in  html tag but it doesn't work. I am using angular 12 btw

Also I install an angular material to my project for the `<mat-slide-toggle>` because I need it, but after I installed it I see no problem with the tags but today (or yesterday)

Comment: If you could provide some code examples of what is not working. From the picture you provided, I cannot start to help.

Comment: Hi i jsut updated my question with some codes. I really don't know what's wrong its just some tags like the <h1> and so on doesn't work. Even my css i've done nothing no changes at all yet this happend

Comment: Your code looks Ok -perhafs you can use "safe operator" `x?.FName`, `x?.Mname`,.. to avoid if not defined the properties in your customer- what do you want to say with "not working"? if it's that not get the .css check if you're override it in any way